# What is replacement of EventTimeSourceFunction (Flink 0.10.x) in Flink 1.x?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to migrate the [SlidingArrivalCount.scala](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-streaming-demo/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/dataartisans/flink_demo/examples/SlidingArrivalCount.scala) example which is based on Flink 0.10.1 to Flink 1.1.1.

The `TaxiRideSource` data stream source used in the example implements the `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.EventTimeSourceFunction` interface, which is no longer provided by Flink 1.x.

How can port `TaxiRideSource` to Flink 1.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Flink 1.0.0, all `SourceFunction` can operate in Event time mode, i.e., they have the interfaces in place to do so.

Source functions that implement `EventTimeSourceFunction` can be upgraded to Flink 1.x, by replacing `EventTimeSourceFunction` by `SourceFunction`.